# jQuery ajax returns entire page content instead of result

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have to add functionality to a VS 2008 (.Net 3.5) web site that is using Synapse's content management system.  After struggling for many hours I started from scratch and the following works in a brand new web project.

Here is the client-side script and html:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function ClickedIt() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Default.aspx/FromClient",
        data: "{}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(msg) {
            alert(msg.d);
        }
    });
} // ClickedIt
function ClickedItDeeper() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Deeper/ActionsController.aspx/FromClient",
        data: "{}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(msg) {
            alert(msg.d);
        }
    });
} // ClickedItDeeper
</script>

<asp:Button ID="btnClickMe" runat="server" Text="Click Me - Server" />&nbsp;&nbsp;
<asp:Button ID="btnViaClient" runat="server" Text="Click Me - Client" OnClientClick="ClickedIt(); return false;" />&nbsp;&nbsp;
<asp:Button ID="btnDeeper" runat="server" Text="Click Me - Deeper" OnClientClick="ClickedItDeeper(); return false;" />
```

Even better yet, I have to write it in VB, so here are the two different tests I am calling.  One is the actual page I am running (Default.aspx) and the other is the way I like to do it to keep the methods together (ActionsController.aspx):

```
Imports System.Web.Services

  Partial Public Class _Default
  Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub btnClickMe_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnClickMe.Click
    Me.lblResult.Text = "From the Server Side: " + DateTime.Now.ToString()
End Sub

<WebMethod()> _
Public Shared Function FromClient() As String
    Return "Via the Client: " + DateTime.Now.ToString()
End Function

End Class
```

The ActionsController is:

```
Imports System.Web.Services

Partial Public Class ActionsController
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

<WebMethod()> _
Public Shared Function FromClient() As String
    Return "Via the Deeper Client: " + DateTime.Now.ToString()
End Function

End Class
```

All of the above works like a champ in that isolated site.  However, when I try to do the same thing in this CMS site, I get a:  parseerror: invalid character.  After looking at many MANY articles out there (none fixed it) one had mentioned that perhaps the telerik or even the CMS software was overwriting JSON.parse and it seems as if it was.  I forced it to not use the other and now it is using json2.js.  When I put an:

```
alert(text);
```

just inside the json2.js file:

```
JSON.parse = function(text, reviver) {
```

it shows me the entire html page content, which is the page not found when I call it with this:

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "ActionsController.aspx/FromClient",
data: "{}",
contentType: "application/json",
dataType: "json",
success: function(msg) {
    $("#lblResult").html(msg);
    alert("success");
},
error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert("Ajax error on " + this.url +
        "\nStatus: " + textStatus +
        "\nError: " + errorThrown +
        "\nText: " + xhr.statusText +
        "\nxhrStatus: " + xhr.status
    );
}
});
```

Gives me a error of SyntaxError: JSON.parse but a text value of OK and status of 200.

I have changed the URL to not have the leading / and added en-US to the start with and without the leading slash all to no avail.  I am not sure if the page not found is legit.  Initially the ActionsController page was in a folder.  I have since moved it to the root of the site.

This is something I have done so many times on VS2010.  It works in VS2008 but I figure something is getting in the way and either attaching something to the URL or something thanks to this CMS.  When it errors, I do have it passing me the this.url which is: /ActionsController.aspx/FromClient so that works for me.

Here is the actual ActionsController code for broken site:

```
Imports System.Web.Services

Partial Public Class ActionsController
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

<WebMethod()> _
 Public Shared Function FromClient() As String
    Return "Via the Deeper Client: " + DateTime.Now.ToString()
End Function

<WebMethod()> _
Public Shared Function Multiply(ByVal Input As Integer) As String
    Return "Via the Deeper Client: " + DateTime.Now.ToString()
End Function

End Class
```

One more hour and it will be a full day of just searching and tweaking and testing on something that is probably so simple but hidden beneath layers and layers of "functionality" from telerik and synapse.

Please make my day!

Comment: would it matter if you pass null for the data instead of {}

Comment: It appears as though the main problem will be the path you are using to reach the service isn't reaching the service, clued by the *"page not found"* you are getting.

Comment: @AndrewWalters I tried that and no.  No difference, thank you though.

Comment: @KevinB I mentioned that above.  In order to verify the path is correct, I have the ActionsController page showing "This is the actions controller".  The test page has some buttons on it and is at http://localhost:2940/Test.aspx.  I then opened a new tab and put in http://localhost:2940/ActionsController.aspx and it shows my "This is the actions controller"  So I tried /ActionsController.aspx/FromClient and it doesn't work.  I even forced it to http://localhost:2940/ActionsController.aspx/FromClient and it did not work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, after a bit of talking with the developer I wound up getting enough information to figure it out.  There were basically two things I had to do to make it work.  One, I had to override the BeginRequest in the Global.asax file and then add some values to the web.config.

In case anyone else comes across an issue like this, here is the complete result.

On the .aspx page, here is the jQuery ajax call:

```
function LoadAllScannedDocumentCounts() {
    var labels = $("[data-DocumentFolder]");

    $.each(labels, function(index, label) {
        var ComplaintNumber = $(this).attr("data-DocumentFolder");
        $(this).prepend("<img id='spinImage" + ComplaintNumber + "' src='/ComplaintsReports/Images/spinner.gif' />");

        $.ajax({
            url: "/Exclusions/ActionsController.aspx/GetScannedDocumentCount",
            type: "POST",
            data: "{ " +
                    "       'ComplaintNumber': '" + ComplaintNumber + "'" +
                " }",
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
                $(label).text(data.d);

                if (data.d > 0)
                    $(label).addClass("badge badge-info");
                else
                    $(label).addClass("badge");
            }, // Success
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert("Error: " + errorThrown + "\nURL: " + this.url);
            } // Error
        }); // Ajax
    }); // foreach of the checked check boxes
} // LoadAllScannedDocumentCounts - Method
```

The web.config addition:

```
<system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
        <webServices>
            <authenticationService enabled="true" />
        </webServices>
    </scripting>
</system.web.extensions>
```

The Global.asax file:

Imports System.Web.SessionState

```
Public Class Global_asax
Inherits SynapseBaseSite46.Global

Sub Application_BeginRequest(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.BeginRequest
    Dim app As HttpApplication = DirectCast(sender, HttpApplication)
    Dim con As HttpContext = app.Context

    ' Skip any calls to the ActionsController
    If (Not con.Request.FilePath.ToLower().Contains("exclusions/actionscontroller.aspx")) Then
        MyBase.Application_BeginRequest(sender, e)
    End If
End Sub

End Class
```

And lastly, the "ActionsController" page with the WebMethods on it:

```
Imports System.Web.Services
Imports System.IO

Partial Public Class ActionsController
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

<WebMethod()> _
 Public Shared Function GetScannedDocumentCount(ByVal ComplaintNumber As String) As Integer
    Dim Result As Integer = 0
    Dim SearchPath As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ScannedImagesShare") & "\"

    Try
        For Each dir As DirectoryInfo In New DirectoryInfo(SearchPath & ComplaintNumber.Replace("-", "")).GetDirectories()
            Dim files As FileInfo() = dir.GetFiles("*.pdf")
            Result += files.Count()
        Next
    Catch dex As DirectoryNotFoundException
        ' do nothing
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try

    Return Result
 End Function

End Class
```